# ¿Limitar fechas anteriores en ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic

Estoy trabajando con un input datetime en ionic y quiero restringir las fechas anteriores a la actual

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Fecha</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMMM YYYY" formControlName="date"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia o idea para implementarlo

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Puedes mostrar el código (en texto y no en imagen) del elemento que utilizas para tu selector de fecha? Si usas un `input` de tipo `date`, basta con implementar lo que pone la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date#max). Saludos

Comment: Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera: creando una variable today; any; y un metodo   getDate() {
    const date = new Date();
    this.today = date.getFullYear() + '-'
             + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-'
             + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
             console.log(this.today);
  }   luego le paso today por el html min='today' pero me sale error

Comment: segun la documentacion de ionic deberia bastar con agregar el atributo `min` al elemento `ion-datetime`. Si te arroja algun error, puedes editar la pregunta complementando con el codigo que probaste y el error en consola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código para obtener la fecha actual es correcto. Debes añadir al elemento ion-datetime el atributo min, así: [min]

```js
  today: any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getDate();  
      
  }

  getDate() { const date = new Date(); this.today = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2); console.log(this.today); }
```

```html
  <ion-datetime [min]="today" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMMM YYYY" formControlName="date"></ion-datetime>
```